# Unable to delete user in Preferences

Tags: macos, user-account

[image]

I've unlocked the Users & Groups preferences pane, nevertheless I'm unable to select the user "username" for deletion. How can I delete the account?

Comment: Check if that user is still logged in to the system?

Comment: i logged out and while deleting not accepting username and password

Comment: Can you please clarify at _what_ point is and _which_ username/password combination is not accepted?

Comment: You need at least *one* admin user.  Create a new one, log in, then attempt to delete the account

Comment: Was `username` the first account created? If so, that account has links to OS services that will prevent it from being deleted (though you could hide it). If this is the case and you really want it gone, see: https://medium.com/@ambroselittle/cant-delete-original-admin-user-on-macos-high-sierra-1d79fb438246

Comment: @NimeshNeema my login password for that User

Comment: @Allan I Have Gowthaman D is the Admin user

Comment: @Jon Your Idea is working Thank You and Add This as Answer Everyone  can Use This and i will approve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Was `username` the first account created? If so, that account has links to OS services that will prevent it from being deleted (though you could hide it). If this is the case and you really want it gone, you can reassign the `GeneratedUID` from that account to your preferred account and then delete the original. For detailed instructions on how to do this, see [Ambrose Little's site](https://medium.com/@ambroselittle/cant-delete-original-admin-user-on-macos-high-sierra-1d79fb438246).